Can Shor's algorithm be improved transfering the classical part into the quantum part?
Shor's algorithm was suggested 20 years ago. But it has still globally unavailable in real world.
In my opinion, one reason of that is shor's algorithm includes both classical part and quantum part.
So, why could not people transfer classical part into quantum part?

Welcome to QCSE. The classical part is not difficult. It’s the quantum part that is the most difficult. But, people have made improvements in the last 30 years. I recommend you read this Quanta magazine article: https://www.quantamagazine.org/thirty-years-later-a-speed-boost-for-quantum-factoring-20231017/

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

@MarkSpinelli instead of closing this, why not write that as an answer?

Thanks @user1271772Nomorefreetime. I don’t feel strongly one way or the other. There’s the idea that answering such questions encourages similar questions, but also the idea that answers in comments are far from ideal as well.

I don't think it's a bad question for a beginner. If you could answer it, then how can it need more details/clarity? It seems that the user wants to know "why not speed up the classical part using a quantum computer" and that the answer "the classical part is already fast" is a good one! What do we have to discourage?

There may be more to this question. As it stands the classical component of Shor's scales as the higher degree polynomial. Perhaps they are asking whether the classical part of the algorithm can be integrated into the quantum to reduce the overall polynomial scaling?

@EthanDavies what do you mean by "the" higher degree polynomial? Also, the scaling if Shor's algorithm is poly-log, not poly-nomial.

I meant poly in  number of digits so we should be ok? https://www.qi.damtp.cam.ac.uk/files/PartIIIQC/Part%202%20QIC%20lecturenotes.pdf page 87 goes into it here. The post processing involves running Euclid to find the GCD which runs in n^3. Surprisingly this makes the whole algorithm run in n^3 time and determines the complexity of Shor's.

@EthanDavies reviewing p. 87 of Jozsa's lecture notes, it is not Euclid's GCD or LSM algorithm in any pre- or post-processing step that runs in time $O(n^3)$; rather, it is the modular exponentiation by repeated squaring that is the $O(n^3)$ bottleneck - this is done in superposition.

My bad it's page 88, last 3 paragraphs.

@EthanDavies thanks I’m not sure I understand those paragraphs… Euclid’s algorithm is famously linear in the number of bits of $a$ and $b$. I’ll study Jozsa’s notes in more detail. Thanks for linking them!

@MarkSpinelli the number of steps is logarithmic, but computing the modulus of large numbers isn't constant which makes it more complicated. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3980416/time-complexity-of-euclids-algorithm Craig Gidney goes into it a bit here.

The current difficulties in implementing at useful scales Shor's algorithm have nothing to do with the "classical part" in the algorithm.
The issue is that the technological state of the art doesn't allow us to build sufficiently large and accurate quantum computers to implement the quantum part (at useful scales). In fact, "including the classical part into the quantum part" would most likely only make the algorithm even harder to implement in practice, with present-day technology.
I should also point out that any quantum algorithm will include a "classical part" on top of a "quantum part". That's just a restatement of the fact that you have to somehow (classically) post-process the measurement data you get from the quantum device at some point. You might argue that can be made into a somewhat trivial step, if outcome probabilities already directly encode the solution to the problem, but it's still a "classical step" that's always there.
This is not to say that there can't be a quantum algorithm that is more efficient than Shor's. There's no proof or evidence to that effect as far as I'm aware. But then again, there's also no proof nor evidence pointing towards there not being a classical algorithm that is more efficient than Shor's quantum one anyway.

To factor $N$, Shor's algorithm has a number of portions that can broadly be interpreted as a "classical part" -

The pre-processing, including testing to see if $N$ is odd or a prime power, drawing a test seed $a$ uniformly at random from $[1, N]$, and confirming that $\gcd(a,N)=1$;
The post-processing, including running the continued fraction algorithm to extract the period $r$ with $a^x\bmod N=a^{x+r}\bmod N$; and
Giving a classical description of a quantum circuit to actually evaluate $a^x\bmod N$ in superposition.

As to parts 1 and 2, as hinted in the comments and the other answer there is no need to run these on a quantum computer precisely because our classical algorithms are already very efficient.  We learn how to tell whether a number is even or odd in maybe first grade, and we learn Euclid's algorithm to determine the greatest common divisors in maybe fifth grade; the continued fraction portion is a little trickier but it's still based on some version of Euclid's algorithm to take the least common multiple, relying on the Chinese remainder theorem.
As to the third portion - how to build a quantum circuit to evaluate $x^a\bmod N$ in superposition - Shor's original FOCS paper doesn't discuss how this would actually be done but his extended paper gives pseudocode for modular exponentiation by repeated squaring.  Regardless, it is this, and not the GCD calculation etc., that is the main bottleneck for all of the time-complexity breakdowns of Shor's algorithm.  It's also my understanding that this is where Regev's recent work gets a significant speedup.
The Wikipedia article on Shor's algorithm also hints that we can either directly implement Shor's pseudocode as a classical reversible circuit or actually use inner quantum Fourier transforms when we evaluate $a^x\bmod N$ in superposition, much like the Schönhage–Strassen algorithm uses classical fast Fourier transforms for fast multiplication, so as to get a better asymptotic speedup of the modular exponentiation calculations.
Indeed Shor's extended paper even states:

One tantalizing fact is that the Schönhage–Strassen fast multiplication algorithm uses the fast Fourier transform, which is also the basis for all the fast algorithms on quantum computers discovered to date; it is tempting to speculate that integer multiplication itself might be speeded up by a quantum algorithm... (emphasis added).

